# Include path of object when streaming out JSON from JQ

Tags: json, path, bigdata, jq

I've got the following (100GB+) JSON file which includes the following top level key:

```json
{
   "data": {
      "<userId1>": {
         "things": {
            "<thingId1>": {
               "subfield1": "blah1",
               "subfield3": "foobar",
            },
            "<thingId2>": {
               "subfield2": "blah2"
            }
         }
      },
      "<userId2>": {
         "things": {
            "<thingId1>": {
               "subfield4": "blah3"
            },
            "<thingId2>": {
               "subfield3": "blah4"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I'd like each `things` object outputted with its path on a new line (for later newline delimited JSON usage down the pipeline), e.g. with the above it would output:

```
{ "path": "data/<userId1>/things/<thingId1>", "value": { "subfield1": "blah1", "subfield3": "foobar" } }
{ "path": "data/<userId1>/things/<thingId2>", "value": { "subfield2": "blah2" } }
{ "path": "data/<userId2>/things/<thingId1>", "value": { "subfield4": "blah3" } }
{ "path": "data/<userId2>/things/<thingId2>", "value": { "subfield3": "blah4" } }
```

The separators in `path` can be `.` if needed but would be most useful if it was an actual string array of keys.

It also needs to be a bit generic as I'd also like the simpler case of:

```json
{
   "users": {
      "<userId1>": {
         "name": "user1",
         "email": "foo@bar.com"
      },
      "<userId2>": {
         "name": "user2"
      },
      "<userId3>": {
         "email": "hello@world.com"
      }
   }
}
```

To produce the output of:

```
{ "path": "users/<userId1>", "value": { "name": "user1", "email": "foo@bar.com" } }
{ "path": "users/<userId2>", "value": { "name": "user2" } }
{ "path": "users/<userId3>", "value": { "email": "hello@world.com" } }
```

For the simpler case, I've managed to get JQ to output the `key` of each object with:

```bash
echo '{"users":{"<userId1>":{"name":"user1"},"<userId2>":{"name":"user2"}}}' | jq -rn --stream 'fromstream(1 | truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "users"))) | to_entries | map("\(. | tojson)") | join("\n")'
```

And while that works, I can't quite work out how to adapt it to output paths for the nested objects in the more complex example.

Also JQ-wise I don't know if piping the output of `fromstream` to more functions is realistic memory wise? We're talking about 10s of millions of `users`/`data` sub objects and possibly a similar amount of `things` sub objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could still `--stream` the input but write your own interpreter that extracts and processes the parts needed. Here's an example that collects the content parts (having a value at position `1`) into a result object (using `setpath`). The original path is split at two levels below the deepest occurrence of either `things` or `users` (or ignored, if neither was present), with the lower part being used for `setpath`, and the higher part being compared to the previously processed items's higher part path. If they match, the next item is added, otherwise a new result object is started while the old, "finished" one is returned (and discarded from memory after the first item of the next result object is added).

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env -S jq --stream -ncf

foreach (

  ( inputs | select(has(1))
  | (first | [rindex("things", "users")] | max | values) as $p
  | [.[0][$p+2:], (.[0][:$p+2] | join("/")), .[1]]), [[]]

) as [$vpath, $path, $value] ([];

  if [first.path, $path] | unique[1]
  then [{$path}, first] else .[:1] end
  | first.value |= setpath($vpath; $value);

  .[1] | values
)
```

```json
{"path":"data/<userId1>/things/<thingId1>","value":{"subfield1":"blah1","subfield3":"foobar"}}
{"path":"data/<userId1>/things/<thingId2>","value":{"subfield2":"blah2"}}
{"path":"data/<userId2>/things/<thingId1>","value":{"subfield4":"blah3"}}
{"path":"data/<userId2>/things/<thingId2>","value":{"subfield3":"blah4"}}
{"path":"users/<userId1>","value":{"name":"user1","email":"foo@bar.com"}}
{"path":"users/<userId2>","value":{"name":"user2"}}
{"path":"users/<userId3>","value":{"email":"hello@world.com"}}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WhfkoOCIUJO) (faking the stream with the `tostream` filter added, as there's no `--stream` option in jqplay)

Comment: This is looking really good - thanks! One Q - if I have other top level nodes with `things` (ie. not just `data` in the example), will I need to pipe `inputs` to `select(has(1) and .[0][0] == "data")` instead to only care about that node?

Comment: @Rich Yes, with `and .[0][0] == "data"` added, everything **not** under `.data` will be completely disregarded (also regardless of  `things` or `users` occuring in their paths or not). And for all the paths below `.data` the criteria will be as before (i.e. depending on an occurrence of either `things` or `users`, then cutting two levels before the deepest of them). Btw, you could also parametrize that list of field names for more flexibility.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise I hadn't accepted this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to the first (revised) problem. It addresses the size problem by using "JSON Machine" to break up the giant blob, which hopefully can then be handled by jq in a straightforward way.

In the following, the `jm` command-line tool is used to simplify use of "JSON Machine". If you prefer a similar Python-based interface, you could use the jm.py command-line tool. See https://github.com/pkoppstein/jm for further details about jm and jm.py

```
jm < input.json |
 jq -c 'to_entries[] 
  | .key as $uid
  | .value.things
  | to_entries[]
  | {path: "data/\($uid)/things/\(.key)", value}
'
```

This produces the required output for the first example.

The above can be made more general in several ways, but the approach is so straightforward that it might be easier to adapt the program as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to the first (revised) problem using jq's streaming parser.

```
jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))
  | to_entries[] 
  | .key as $uid
  | .value.things
  | to_entries[]
  | {path: "data/\($uid)/things/\(.key)", value}
' input.json
```

The first line of the jq program (i.e., the `fromstream` line) breaks up the giant blob into pieces that can then be handled in a straightforward way.

The above program of course is not generic but its approach (first breaking up the giant blob, and then managing the pieces) is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic approach that can be used with jq's streaming parser, or with "JSON Machine" as described elsewhere on this page.

First, start with:

```
< input.json jq -cn --stream '
  def pathValue($n):
    if $n == 1 
    then to_entries[]
    | {path: .key, value}
    else to_entries[]
    | (.value|pathValue($n-1)) as $pv
    | {path: (.key + "/" + $pv.path), value: $pv.value}
    end;

  fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))
  | pathValue(3)
'
```

For the first example, this produces:

```
{"path":"<userId1>/things/<thingId1>","value":{"subfield1":"blah1","subfield3":"foobar"}}
{"path":"<userId1>/things/<thingId2>","value":{"subfield2":"blah2"}}
{"path":"<userId2>/things/<thingId1>","value":{"subfield4":"blah3"}}
{"path":"<userId2>/things/<thingId2>","value":{"subfield3":"blah4"}}
```

The first step loses the top-level key, so you'd have to add it back in if you really want it.  If you want to determine it programatically without consuming more than a trivial amount of memory or time, you could, for example,
use

```
jq -n --stream 'first(inputs|first|first)'
```

For the second example, you'd call `pathValue(1)`.