# Include path of any object when streaming out JSON from JQ

Tags: json, bigdata, jq

I'd like to be able to extract specific JSON objects from huge (100GB+) JSON files by specifying a wildcard lookup.
(While my end goal is having a path type string for lookups, I'm more than happy to process this string into a `jq` filter - the `jq` filter for streaming is what I'm having issues with).
Ideally I'd like to only use `jq`.

The format of my files are the following:

File 1:

```json
{
   "data": {
      "<userId1>": {
         "things": {
            "<thingId1>": {
               "subfield1": "blah1",
               "subfield3": "foobar"
            },
            "<thingId2>": {
               "subfield2": "blah2"
            }
         }
      },
      "<userId2>": {
         "things": {
            "<thingId1>": {
               "subfield4": "blah3"
            },
            "<thingId2>": {
               "subfield3": "blah4"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "users": {
      "<userId1>": {
         "name": "user1",
         "email": "foo@bar.com"
      },
      "<userId2>": {
         "name": "user2"
      },
      "<userId3>": {
         "email": "hello@world.com"
      }
   }
}
```

File 2 (a more simple list of objects by keys):

```json
{
   "<key1>": {
      "subfield1": "blah1",
      "subfield3": "foobar"
   },
   "<key2>": {
      "subfield2": "blah2"
   }
}
```

File 3 (a deeply keyed list of objects):

```json
{
   "<key1>": {
      "<subKey1A>": {
         "<deeperKey1A>": {
            "subfield1": "blah1",
            "subfield3": "foobar"
         },
         "<deeperKey2A>": {
            "subfield1": "blah1",
            "subfield4": "foobar4"
         }
      },
      "<subKey2A>": {
         "<deeperKey2A>": {
            "subfield4": "foobar4"
         }
      }
   },
   "<key2>": {
      "<subKey1B>": {
         "<deeperKey2B>": {
            "subfield1": "blah1",
            "subfield4": "foobar4"
         }
      },
      "<subKey2B>": {
         "<deeperKey1B>": {
            "subfield1": "blah1",
            "subfield3": "foobar"
         },
         "<deeperKey3B>": {
            "subfield4": "foobar6"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In both the above cases any `<blah>` keys are arbitrary IDs.

I'd like the output for the following files - the search is the wildcard type look up I'd like to achieve - think of the `$<>` paths as "this matches anything" (maybe using `*` is clearer but I like that it helps identify what the wildcard component is when reading it...).
I've also included the specific `jq` filters for each case I've gotten to work.

File 1 - for the `data/$userId/things/$thingId` search:

```
{ "path": ["data", "<userId1>", "things", "<thingId1>"], "value": { "subfield1": "blah1", "subfield3": "foobar" } }
{ "path": ["data", "<userId1>", "things", "<thingId2>"], "value": { "subfield2": "blah2" } }
{ "path": ["data", "<userId2>", "things", "<thingId1>"], "value": { "subfield4": "blah3" } }
{ "path": ["data", "<userId2>", "things", "<thingId1>"], "value": { "subfield3": "blah4" }
```

`jq` filter:

```
foreach (

  ( inputs | select(has(1) and ((.[0] | length) >= 4) and .[0][0] == "data" and .[0][2] == "things")
  | (first | [rindex("things")] | max | values) as $p
  | [.[0][$p+2:], .[0][:$p+2], .[1]]), [[]]

) as [$vpath, $path, $value] ([];

  if [first.path, $path] | unique[1]
  then [{$path}, first] else .[:1] end
  | first.value |= setpath($vpath; $value);

  .[1] | values
)
```

File 1 - for the `users/$userId` search:

```
{ "path": ["users", "<userId1>"], "value": { "name": "user1", "email": "foo@bar.com" } }
{ "path": ["users", "<userId2>"], "value": { "name": "user2" } }
{ "path": ["users", "<userId3>"], "value": { "email": "hello@world.com" } }
```

`jq` filter:

```
foreach (

  ( inputs | select(has(1) and ((.[0] | length) >= 1) and .[0][0] == "users")
  | (first | [rindex("users")] | max | values) as $p
  | [.[0][$p+2:], .[0][:$p+2], .[1]]), [[]]

) as [$vpath, $path, $value] ([];

  if [first.path, $path] | unique[1]
  then [{$path}, first] else .[:1] end
  | first.value |= setpath($vpath; $value);

  .[1] | values
)
```

File 2 - for the `$key` search:

```
{ "path": ["<key1>"], "value": { "subfield1": "blah1", "subfield3": "foobar" } }
{ "path": ["<key2>"], "value": { "subfield2": "blah2" } }
```

I stumbled on to a partial solution for this while messing around with adapting the above filters:

```
foreach (

  ( inputs | select(has(1) and ((.[0] | length) >= 1))
  | (first | [-1] | max | values) as $p
  | [.[0][$p+2:], .[0][:$p+2], .[1]]), [[]]

) as [$vpath, $path, $value] ([];

  if [first.path, $path] | unique[1]
  then [{$path}, first] else .[:1] end
  | first.value |= setpath($vpath; $value);

  .[1] | values
)
```

This almost works, but outputs duplicate entries (the same number as the number of keys in the child object):

```
{ "path": ["<key1>"], "value": { "subfield1": "blah1", "subfield3": "foobar" } }
{ "path": ["<key1>"], "value": { "subfield1": "blah1", "subfield3": "foobar" } }
{ "path": ["<key2>"], "value": { "subfield2": "blah2" } }
```

I don't really understand why replacing `[rindex("some-key")]` with `[-1]` produces this output!

File 3 - for the `$key/$subKey/$deeperKey` search:

```
{ "path": ["<key1>", "<subKey1A>", "<deeperKey1A>"], "value": { "subfield1": "blah1", "subfield3": "foobar" } }
{ "path": ["<key1>", "<subKey1A>", "<deeperKey2A>"], "value": { "subfield1": "blah1", "subfield4": "foobar4" } }
{ "path": ["<key1>", "<subKey2A>", "<deeperKey2A>"], "value": { "subfield4": "foobar4" } }
{ "path": ["<key2>", "<subKey1B>", "<deeperKey2B>"], "value": { "subfield1": "blah1", "subfield4": "foobar4" } }
{ "path": ["<key2>", "<subKey2B>", "<deeperKey1B>"], "value": { "subfield1": "blah1", "subfield3": "foobar" } }
{ "path": ["<key2>", "<subKey2B>", "<deeperKey1C>"], "value": { "subfield4": "foobar6" } }
```

I've managed to get this to work a bit with the above filters again, but all that I could get printed out was the first key (`<key1>`) with `value` being the object nested under its parent paths (`{ "<subKey1A>": { "<deeperKey1A>": { "subfield1": "blah1", "subfield3": "foobar" } } }`).

#### Note

This could be classed as a duplicate of [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76905501/include-path-of-object-when-streaming-out-json-from-jq), and while that has a great answer I still need some more flexibility and didn't want to go changing that question (which I already had once) removing meaning from the excellent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first assume the input JSON is small enough that we don't have to use the streaming parser.

For simplicity, let's also assume that the queries are presented as JSON arrays with "*" as the wildcard.
So the first query would be: `["data", "*", "things", "*"]`

Next, let's define a helper function:

```
# matchesQuery($array) evaluates to true iff the input is an array that matches the array $array
# in the sense that there is elementwise matching of as many elements as there are in $array,
# it being understood that "*" in $array is like a wildcard.
def matchesQuery($array):
  . as $in
  | type == "array"
    and length >= ($array|length)
    and all(range(0; $array|length); . as $i | $array[$i] | IN("*", $in[$i]));
```

The following filter can then be used to pose queries:

```
def query($query):
  . as $in
  | ($query|length) as $ql
  | paths
  | select(length == $ql and matchesQuery($query)) as $path
  | ($in | getpath($path)) as $value
  | {$path, $value} ;
```

For example, executing `query( ["data", "*", "things", "*"] )` against
the first file produces the desired output.

We can next adapt the above for use with jq's streaming parser by wrapping `query/1` as follows:

```
def streamQuery($query):
  fromstream(inputs
    | . as $in
    | if ( length == 2 )
      then select( .[0] | matchesQuery($query))
      else . 
      end )
  | query($query);
```

Finally, let's add a "main" program

```
streamQuery( $query )
```

so that we can specify the query on the command line:

```
jq -n --stream --argjson query '["data", "*", "things", "*"]' -c -f streamQuery.jq  file1.json
```

Comment: This answer is excellent and managed to get it all working but eventually I still run out of memory for the big file, as soon as the stream hits the objects it's looking for the memory just goes up and up and up... :(

Comment: @Rich - What happens if you simply run `jq -c --stream . file1.json > /dev/null` ?  That is, is the file too big even for --stream ?  Have you tried using  gojq with the --stream option?  `gron --json`?

Comment: Yeh I’ve been piping it to `/dev/null` to test and so far I’ve managed to get it to work with 500GB of memory (which while it works isn’t really cost effective! ) I’ll look into gojq/ `gron`

Comment: Oh missed the `.` filter in your command, shall try that. FWIW running a slightly different filter (e.g `/data/*/things2/*/*`) on the JSON causes the OOM issue, the original `/data/*/things/*` is fine on the same JSON.

Comment: `jq -c --stream . file1.json > /dev/null` runs fine using a tiny amount of memory so it's something about collating the `/data/*/things2/*/*` records (there's 380m of them...). I've still not completely got my head around jq streaming yet but is there anything that can be done around garbage collection or deleting an outputted object to clean up after it's been processed. The memory only starts to increase when processing matching path is started. (Shall look into `gron` and `gojq` tomorrow - at least `gron` looks like it might be useful to at least filter on a single root node!)

Comment: It might be worth looking at jm (https://github.com/pkoppstein/jm)

Comment: I don't think it'll help as you can't do `-` for object keys like you can arrays with pointers, ideally `jm -s --pointer "/data/-/things2/-/-"` would work so only 1 deep big object is processed at once - though I'd have the same problem about not knowing the parent path of the output

Comment: I've assumed that's what you meant when you mentioned `jm`?

Comment: I had in mind combining jm and jq in some way to approximate a solution to your needs, e.g. using jm to fetch .data and then jq for the needed flexibility.

Comment: I'll have a play but I think that the objects at `/data/*/things2/*/*` are just too big and slowly add up? What I don't understand is that I'm using `-c` option for `jq` to output each object and the filter matches on a single object and then moves on to the next one so why the memory increase? I don't think the size of the JSON (outside of the root `/data` path) matters (memory wise at least, it certainly increases processing time but that's fineish).

Comment: I've yet to look at `gojq` but from your [performance comparsions](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jm#performance-comparisons) it looks to use twice as much memory as `jq`

Comment: I wonder if I can use [JSON machine](https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine/tree/master) directly, and just have nested iteration loops using JSON pointers at each level but I think I'd need [this PR](https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine/pull/36) to be done!

Comment: I think doing something like `jm -s --pointer '/data' | jq --stream -ncf filter.jq` (with some tweaks to your above filter example) will help though, as at least each massive `/data/*` thing will be processed one at a time as opposed to letting `jq` do the per object processing (if that makes sense)! Thanks for all your help btw!